# How to add 1 to html content with every click using javascript

Tags: javascript

New to coding, especially javascript.

My function is not working. When I open the web page and click the button, the number still just appears as 100.

Any idea how to fix this so that with each click of the button the number increases by 1?

```js
var number = document.getElementById("a");
var count = 0;
number.innerHTML = count;

number.onClick = function() {
  count += 1;
};
```

```css
.dev {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button id="a" class='dev'> </button>
```

Comment: Your code only performs the `.innerHTML` assignment *once*. That assignment statement does not create any sort of permanent relationship between the content of the element and the `count` variable. You have to re-assign `.innerHTML` explicitly when you want it to change.

Comment: If I move `number.innerHTML = count;` to the function, would that then fix the problem since the the innerHTML is being assigned with each execution?

Comment: Yes exactly, you have to do the assignment each time `count` is incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spell onClick to 'onclick' and put 'number.innerHTML = count;' inside function.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
    dev {
      display: block;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    </style>

    <!-- HTML -->
    <html>
    <button id="a">0 </button>


    </html>


    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script>
    var number = document.getElementById("a");
    var count = 0;

    number.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      number.innerHTML = count;
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: i hate when it's something so simple as that. you're a genius! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  <button id="a" onclick="increment();"> </button>


  function increment()
  {
      var inc = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
      inc = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      inc++;
      document.getElementById('a').value = inc;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this line in the function

```
number.innerHTML = count;
```

.

```
number.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  number.innerHTML = count;
};
```

Comment: tried this but still getting the same problem. 
http://cloud.invisible.email/b668d30d691d

Answer (score 0):

Use the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and add the click event.

```js
var number = document.getElementById("a");
var count = 0;
number.innerHTML = count;

number.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const cnt = Number(number.innerHTML) + 1
  number.innerHTML = cnt
});
```

```css
dev {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
<button id="a"> </button>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number.onClick = function() {
  count += 1;
};
```

*onClick* should be replaced with *onclick*

Javascript is a case sensitive language, so *onClick* and *onclick* are treated as 2 different words.
 On clicking, you are just changing the value of count variable, but not updating  DOM(Document Object Model).

So the final code should be

```
number.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  number.innerHTML = count;
};
```